# How to sort a collection by a date field?

Tags: java, sorting, date, comparator

I'm trying to sort an album by release date. For some reason I am not getting anywhere:

```java
//sort by release date
Collections.sort(this._items, new Comparator<Album>() {
    public int compare(Album t1, Album t2) {
        int dateCmp = t2.getStartDate().compareTo(t1.getStartDate());
        Log.i("==Albums==", "dateComp: " + dateCmp);
        return t1.getStartDate().compareTo(t2.getStartDate());
    }            
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I see in the output of Foo Fighters Albums by release date:

```
name: There Is Nothing Left To Lose | release date: 11/2/1999
name: Greatest Hits | release date: 11/3/2009
name: Skin And Bones | release date: 11/7/2006
name: Foo Fighters | release date: 12/10/2003
name: DOA | release date: 12/13/2005
name: Rope | release date: 3/1/2011
name: The Colour And The Shape | release date: 3/30/2010
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us code for Album class?

Comment: Why are you logging the _inverse_ of your comparison result?  That's just liable to confuse somebody (unless you rather explicity call it out in the log...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It look like that your `startDate` field is of type [`java.lang.String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). At least, the order in the output confirms that. The [`String#compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) will order `String` values lexicographically, not by the value it represents in the eye of the beholder.

If you change the incorrect type to be [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), or use [`SimpleDateFormat#parse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) to convert the `String` to `Date` inside the `compare()` method and then call [`Date#compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) instead, then the ordering will work as expected.

I'd replace it by `java.util.Date`. Always use the right type for the value it represents.

Comment: yes you are right. I resolved this yesterday and now it compares correctly. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Now yet to fix `mm` to be `MM` before you ask another question where you wonder that months are not properly ordered. I'd still rather use a real `Date` field instead. It ends up in less clumsy code of converting it back and forth from `String` in all comparisions/calculations. If want to present it after al on console, screen or file or whatever, then you could just use `SimpleDateFormat#format()` for this. Even more, most UI libraries/frameworks offer ready-to-use components for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code. The issue was because the start date was of type string.

//sort by release date

```
Collections.sort(this._items, new Comparator<Album>() {    
                        public int compare(Album t1, Album t2) {

                            int dateCmp = 0;

                             try {  

                                SimpleDateFormat formatter; 
                                Date date1; 
                                Date date2; 
                                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

                                date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(t1.getStartDate()); 
                                date2 = (Date)formatter.parse(t2.getStartDate()); 

                                dateCmp = (date2).compareTo(date1);

                              } 
                              catch (Exception e)
                              {
                                //Log.i("==Albums==", "album special sort - error" );
                              }

                            //Log.i("==Albums==", "dateComp: " + dateCmp);

                            return dateCmp; 

                        }               
                    });
```

Comment: `mm` stands for minutes, not months. You want to use `MM` instead. Read the [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for an overview of all patterns.